# how do I make a vertical list print horizontally?

Tags: python, string

If I have a variable that prints out vertically like this:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

How do I make this variable print horizontally like this?:

```
hello
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: You'll probably need to add more details to your question...

Comment: can you show the code and variable that generates the vertical output?

Comment: is it array/list you are printing individual item?

Comment: i just got a solution to this problem from a friend of mine. thanks everyone.

Comment: Got what you want to ask as I have faced this problem too. Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706998/5689801

Answer (score 5):

Assuming

```
text = 'h\ne\nl\nl\no'
```

here is another way.

```
''.join(text.split())
```

Comment: that is a great solution (if only we *knew* what the actual problem is exactly :-/ I think at some point the OP posted something about an image, but then deleted the comment. (still a neat solution). Now that the other answer is gone it might be useful to show `var` initialized

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are creating a string from an array?   Or maybe a string from a string?

```
>>> from_list = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> print ''.join(from_list)
hello
>>> print ':'.join(from_list)
h:e:l:l:o
```

The *join()* function of strings takes a list and returns a string with its argument stuck between each item.

You might be using a string:

```
>>> from_string = "h\ne\nl\nl\no"
>>> print from_string
h
e
l
l
o
>>> print from_string.split()
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> print "".join(from_string.split())
hello
>>> print " (pause) ".join("one, two, three, five, no four!".split(","))
one (pause)  two (pause)  three (pause)  five (pause)  no four!
```

This uses the *split()* function of strings, which splits a string into a list of items.  The result is then joined back into a string.   You can split on any string, but whitespace is the default.

Answer (score 0):

a very shortcut method I can Suggest is like follows

```python
str1 = "I love python"
for chars in str1:
  print( * [chars], end = ' ')
```

**output**

```
 I   l o v e   p y t h o n
```

if you dont want space just remove the space between the single quote
i.e
`print( * [chars], end = '')`

**output**

```
 I love python
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the representation of the list's items with `', '`,

```
l = [3.14, 'string', ('tuple', 'of', 'items')]
print(', '.join(map(repr, l)))
```

Output:

> ```
> 3.14, 'string', ('tuple', 'of', 'items')
> ```

---

I don't know what is meant by a "vertical list" as python only has lists without orientation.